# How to import online script in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to import an online javascript file. Does anybody know how I can import this in a react native project?

Like in HTML:

```
<script 
src="http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.latest.js"
        type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
```

Edit:
I tried to install a library but I got the following error:

```
undefined unable to resolve module 'http' from \node_modules\node-fetch\index.js Module does not exist in the Haste module map.
```

link library:
https://github.com/dsandor/dymojs

In App.js:

```
const Dymo = require("dymojs");
```

Comment: I think that is not posible in react native due to the code is not executed in a browser. You will need to add that lib as a project dependency.

Comment: I also tried to use a library. See edit.

Comment: you cannot do it in that way, check this: https://medium.com/react-native-training/turn-any-javascript-library-into-a-react-native-component-e8ab0c710f12

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
fetch(scriptUrl).then(res => res.text()).then(txt => {
   let js = eval(txt);
   console.log(js);
});
```